# Missing Ram, memory leak?

Tags: linux, memory, opensuse, gnome

I'm running OpenSuse 11 on an HP proliant server with 8G of RAM, occasionally the gnome desktop [whatever is current version]

After a while it will just run out of RAM, there will be like 6 or 700k left available and all the running services don't account for what's missing. If I shut down services in order of physical memory used I still don't find that missing ram till I reboot....

It's a development server - so I can knock it around a bit... but it's kinda irritating having to reboot it periodically...

Anyway - here are the main [important] services in order of :

coldfusion 9 [java]
Mysql 5
Apache 2

Postfix
samba
fetchmail

Gome - occasionally

I was wondering if there were any known issues with suse or any of the services that can cause sucha severe memory issue - generally all those services running should not add up to more than 2G.

Here's what I get after a reboot:

```
suse:~ # free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8192796    1661360    6531436          0      45444    1164404
-/+ buffers/cache:     451512    7741284
Swap:      8384508          0    8384508
```

the memory problems seem to start only after running Gnome.....

-thanks
-sean

Comment: What does `free` look like while it's bad?  What does `top` (press M to sort by memory usage) look like then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have actual memory problems and start hitting the swap, or is just the free memory as reported by free that get's low? In the second case, please read http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: thanks - this looks to be what may be happening, something new to me since I havn't had to install a new linux dist in years and years [they just keep running]   - I'll have to check on the swap usage in a day or two and see where we ar at..